# Show button if another button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, button, if-statement

This is probably very simple, but I need a button to appear if another button is clicked. I am using Visual studio.

This is the process:

1. If this button is clicked: `cmdUpdateBooking`
2. This button will appear: `cmdUpdate`

Sorry to ask a very simple question. A coded example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `cmdUpdate.Visible` property to `False` on your Form `Load` event

```
   Private Sub YourFormName_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cmdUpdate.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

Set `cmdUpdate.Visible` property to `True` on your `cmdUpdateBooking` `Click` event

```
Private Sub cmdUpdateBooking_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdateBooking.Click
    cmdUpdate.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I didn't put the 'cmdUpdate.Visible = True' in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matter if it's `win, web, wpf` or some other GUI for
 this answer.  You set the `cmdUpdate`'s visibility to `false` at design time, and on the click event handler of the second button you change it to `true`.

However if you want a code example you need to tell us if it's web, win, wpf or something else.

Comment: The code is not working: cmdUpdate.Visible = False  If cmdUpdateBooking.Yes = Then cmdUpdate.Visible = True
        End If