# Insert form control button via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a `button` via VBA into my worksheet. Therefore, I tried to go with the simple VBA from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809180/vba-form-control-button-needs-to-disappear-after-another-button-is-clicked).

```
Sub Insert_Button()
Sheet1.Shapes("Button 1").Visible = True
End Sub
```

However, this VBA only works if the button has been inserted and hidden manually before. 
I also tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074520/show-button-if-another-button-is-clicked) but it marked the code red and did not run.

How can I insert a `form control button` via VBA if the button does no exist in the file yet?

Comment: one more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208179/programmatically-add-a-button-with-a-macro-to-an-excel-file

Comment: one more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959244/excel-vba-automatically-add-delete-buttons-depending-on-cell-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(185.25, 61.5, 85.5, 24.75).Select
```

The numbers are co-ordinates, so if you want to add the button to a cell, you would have to use the cell's left/top... like this

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Buttons.Add(.Cells(2, 2).Left, .Cells(2, 2).Top, 85.5, 24.75).Select
End With
```

To include the width and height of a Range like "A1:B2"...

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Buttons.Add(.Cells(1, 1).Left, .Cells(2, 2).Top, .Cells(1, 1).Width + .Cells(1, 2).Width, .Cells(1, 1).Height + .Cells(2, 2).Height).Select
End With
```

Comment: Thanks man for the answer. Is it also possible to set the properties to a range. Let's say the button should appear wihtin cells A1:B2?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl xlButtonControl, 100, 100, 50, 20
```

Numbers are left position, top position, width and height of inserted button